# javascript elements not working

Tags: javascript

I was not able to get part of this javascript code working for unknown reason and display as undefined. How do I merge `vote[1]` into the formObj which is `document.forms[0]` Any other alternate solution?

```
var elements2 = formObj.elements['vote[' + pollId + ']';
```

Comment: You are definitely missing one `]`.

Comment: In post is missing, sorry, but my code has correct code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a basic syntax error:

```
var elements2 = formObj.elements['vote[' + pollId + ']';
```

Should be

```
var elements2 = formObj.elements['vote[' + pollId + ']'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you want:

```
var elements2 = formObj.vote[pollId];
```

(*Assuming "vote" is the name of several form elements*)

You might want to read about [how to handle forms in JavaScript](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a javascript programmer really, but from what I can see above in the code you are missing a "]" at the end of elements.

It looks like your setting elements2 to formObject.elements[i] where you using vote[pollId] as the index. So vote[pollId] should return an integer in this scenario.

I'm not sure if I understand the question

[Javascript Arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_obj_array.asp)

```
var formObj = document.forms[0];
var i = formObj.length + 1;
formObj[i] =  vote[1];
```

Comment: Erm, your code is used to assign the value while I seeking to merge the vote element with document so it would look like document.forms[0].vote[1]